# Encryption algorithm

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography

Do you know a good encryption algorithm that isn't too difficult to implement in c++ (but neither too easy)?

Comment: As a learning experience or for actual use?  (For actual use, the answer is:  don't; use an existing library instead.)

Comment: What do you mean by "too difficult" and "too easy"?

Comment: @James McNellis: it's for an high-school essay

Comment: @unapersson: for too difficult i mean too difficult to implement, understand, study etc...
For too easy i mean that i don't want a banal, algorithm implementable with few rows of code...

Comment: For an essay, you'll probably want to start with ceaser cipher and vigenere cipher.  Then move up to modern ciphers, like RSA (which is pretty simple, but requires basic knowledge of modular arithmetic) and AES

Comment: Too easy: it doesn't exist. If the encryption is strong, it is only good when it is easy to implement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at this [wonderful comics on AES](http://www.moserware.com/2009/09/stick-figure-guide-to-advanced.html). It explains the cryptographic background of the algorithm and you can practice by writing a high-performance implementation of one in different languages.

Answer (score 6):

I think [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA) is good as well as pretty much straightforward to implement. You might want to look into it. Another one I would be suggesting which is also straightforward is [DES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard).

- [Rivest, Shamir and Adleman (RSA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA)
- [Data Encryption Standard (DES)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard)

Comment: my only dubt is explained in the comment that i have done to andand

Comment: @BlackShadow: If you're good in programming, then you can learn RSA in 2 hours, and can implement in it 6 hours (maximum). And almost same for DES. We had done these and other cyptographic problems in our college days.

Answer (score 3):

If you're just looking for something to code up for the learning experience, I've always liked the [Advanced Encryption Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard).  The actual [standard document at NIST](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf) provides all the detail you need to write and test your code.

Comment: thinking that i'm good in programming but i don't know anything about that algorithm...
in your opinion, can i learn that algorithm and implement it in 3-4 days working 2-3 hours each day?

Comment: @BlackShadow: It might take a little while to get your head around some of the math concepts in the standard, but once you get that it's not difficult to program.  You can definitely write the code in the timeframe once you understand the standard.  If you factor in the time to study the standard, you should probably double that time.  Post any questions you have to SO, and you're sure to get some help.

Answer (score 0):

I like [RC5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC5) for its simplicity. Much easier to implement than e.g. [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard), and while not quite as strong, it is still a good cypher.